# Solving a quartic congruence modulo 175

Tags: number-theory

The congruence I'm trying to solve is $x^4 \equiv 71 \pmod{175}$. I really have no idea how to approach this as 175 isn't a power of a prime.

Comment: Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Comment: How would I go about applying it? I've tried solving $x^4=71(mod25)$ and $x^4=71(mod7)$ but that didn't really go anywhere. I got a load of solutions for it but the only ones which were actually correct were 8 and 169, the rest being completely wrong, and I feel that may have been luck!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$x^4\equiv 71\pmod{175}\iff \begin{cases}x^4\equiv 71\equiv 11^2\pmod{25}\\x^4\equiv 71\equiv 1^2\pmod{7}\end{cases}$$

Now remember the identity $a^2-b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$ and [Euclid's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) and the fact that $x^2+11\not\equiv x^2-11\pmod{5}$ :

$$\iff \begin{cases}x^2\equiv \pm 11\pmod{25}\\x^2\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}\end{cases}$$

But $-1$ is not a quadratic residue mod $7$, so:

$$\iff \begin{cases}x^2\equiv \pm 11\pmod{25}\\x^2\equiv 1\pmod{7}\end{cases}\iff \begin{cases}x^2\equiv \pm 11\pmod{25}\\x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}\end{cases}$$

Now check two cases:

- if $x^2\equiv 11\equiv 6^2\pmod{25}$, then $x\equiv \pm 6\pmod{25}$ (similarly like before; notice $x+6\not\equiv x-6\pmod{5}$).

  Also $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}$. Now use the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) (CRT) to get $4$ solutions mod $175$.
- if $x^2\equiv -11\equiv 8^2\pmod{25}$, then $x\equiv \pm 8\pmod{25}$ (similarly like before; notice $x+8\not\equiv x-8\pmod{5}$).

  Also $x\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}$. By CRT you'll get $4$ solutions mod $175$.

Overall, you'll get all the $8$ solutions of the congruence $x^4\equiv 71\pmod{175}$.